# Add Listener to Base Form Field or Fieldset

Tags: extjs3

In ExtJS 3, how to do I go about altering the base Ext.form.Field and Ext.form.Field so that they all have a listener set for the 'hide' event?

I've tried using both Ext.apply and Ext.override to no avail. I don't want to use Extend because then I'd have to extend each different field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Field, {
  initComponent: Ext.form.Field.prototype.initComponent.createSequence(function(){
    this.on({
      ...
    });
  })
});
```